# Updating Readonly Field In Admin Model

Tags: django, admin, readonly

I have a deal model that contains two date field. First one is start_date and the other one is end_date. My aim is when I save a deal I want to update a readonly field which shows the substraction of these two date_field.

I try to write a widget however I can only get one of the fields. Here is my widget:

```
class DueToWidget(AdminDateWidget):                                                                                                                                                                        
    def render(self,name,value,attrs=None):                                                                                                                                                                
        from datetime import timedelta                                                                                                                                                                     
        output = []                                                                                                                                                                                        
        output.append(super(AdminDateWidget, self).render(name,value,attrs))                                                                                                                               
        if value:                                                                                                                                                                                          
            due_to = value + timedelta(days=1)                                                                                                                                                             
            output.append(u'<p>Diff : %s</p>' % due_to)                                                                                                                                   

        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

I'm adding one day to the selected date, how can I get the other field's value ? Or is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having to refresh to see the diff (that is, you only see it after you save the model), then an easier approach is to add a readonly field in the admin, that points to a function, like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('dates_difference',)

    #add your other fields, or put it in a fieldset
    fields = ('dates_difference',)

    def dates_difference(self, model_instance):
        return model_instance.end_date - model_instance.start_date
```

Since your goal is just to display extra information in the model's admin this is the place to put the code, not in a field's widget or the model's class.

As the [readonly_fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) specifies, its behavior is nearly identical as the [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), that is you can point it to attributes on both the model and the model's admin, and also to callables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Override `save()` in the model to save computed data.

```
def save( self, *args, **kw ):
    self.diff = self.end_date - self.start_date
    return super( YourModelClass, self ).save( *args, **kw )
```

Learn more by [reading the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) on the subject.